# HDCP Error on Windows 8 running 4OD

Tags: windows-8, hdmi, hdcp

I've just tried playing a video through the [4OD](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-gb/app/4od/dd5a7bbb-f94a-4b21-adb0-d6ef1e76df55) metro app and I get this error:

```
ERROR_GRAPHICS_OPM_OUTPUT_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_HDCP = 0Xc0262513
```

My setup is:

- Windows 8
- Asus E45M1M DELUXE MB
- AMD Radeon HD 6320 Graphics Card
- HDMI
- Onkyo TX-SR875

Windows says my drivers are up to date:

- Driver Provider: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
- Driver Date: 27/09/2012
- Driver Version: 9.2.0.0

Can anyone suggest how to get this working?

Comment: This error is caused by your display.  Your drivers are also over a year old.

Comment: Unlikely to be display as dedicated Blu-Ray player and HDMI-connected laptop both play protected content perfectly. Currently downloading new drivers from AMD though.

Comment: I've now manually updated drivers via support.amd.com and am now running v13.152.1.8000 dated 08/10/2013. Problem remains exactly the same though :(.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a desktop or mobile graphics card.  My search results are only picking up a mobile part.  We are talking about a full desktop product correct?

Comment: try the 13.11 beta driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx